# Regex returning partial result

Tags: python, regex

Regex is returning only partial result

I have below regex which is returning only partial result
Basically i am trying to find 2 consecutive words followed by a word which contains 
at least 1 upper and lower case letters
at least 1 digit

I am able to match the result but only get the first 2 words not the third word as result. Also seems like the length condition is not working as provided i.e. between 8 and 32

```
def findWordandCode(w1, w2, sentence):

  return re.search(r'\b{0}(?:\W+\w+){{0,1}}\W+{1}\s*(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]){{8,32}}'.format(w1, w2), sentence)
```

For example .

```
findWordandCode('word1','word2','word1 word2, abcABC123! blah blah')
```

this returns only `word1 word2`

Expected result : `word1 word2 abcABC123!`

Comment: Try using an online regex debugger to see how your regex will interpret the strings https://regex101.com/

Comment: `{0,1}` can be abbreviated to just `?`.

Comment: Why do you expect `abcABC123!` to be included in the result? It's matched by the lookahead, and lookarounds aren't included in the match.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function the following way:

```
def findWordandCode(w1, w2, sentence):
    m = re.search(r'\b{0}\s{1},\s'
        '(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[a-z])\S{{8,32}}(?=[\s|$])'\
        .format(w1, w2), sentence)
    return m.group() if m else ''
```

Let's start the description from the regex:

1. Between *word1* (`{0}`) and *word2* (`{1}`) there should be a space,
   or maybe a sequence of spaces (`\s+`).
2. After *word2* there must be a comma and a space (`,\s`).
3. Then each positive lookahead should have `\S*` at the start instead
   of `.*`. With a dot such a lookahead can go to the next word, but you
   actually should check within the current word.
4. After all 3 lookaheads, for a digit, lower-case letter and upper-case letter,
   there should be the part matching this third word - between 8 and 32
   non-space chars.
5. At the end, to protect from longer words, there should be another
   positive lookahead for either a space or the end of string.

And now as the whole function is concerned:

1. Start from the *re.search*, but remember that if nothing has been matched,
   the result is *None*.
2. Then, if match has been found, return it (`m.group()`).
3. If not, return the empty string (or choose another "failed" value,
   e.g. *None*).

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the pattern `(?=.*[a-z]){8,32}` repeats the positive lookahead asserting for a lowercase char 8 - 32 times.

If you want the length of the third word to be 8 - 32 non whitespace chars long you could use `\S{8,32}(?!\S)`

In your pattern, you are not actually matching the third word.

In the lookaheads you could use negation making use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) adding a whitespace char to not cross boundaries.

You might use:

```
\bword1(?:[ \t]+\S+)*\W+word2\b.*?\s+(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z\s]*[\sa-z])\S{8,32}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LnxFYP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LKReh3)

You code could look like

```
import re

def findWordandCode(w1, w2, sentence):
    return re.search(r'\b{0}(?:[ \t]+\S+)*\W+{1}\b.*?\s+(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z\s]*[\sa-z])\S{{8,32}}(?!\S)'.format(w1, w2), sentence)

res = findWordandCode('word1','word2','word1 word2, abcABC123! blah blah')

if res:
    print(res.group())
```

Result

```
word1 word2, abcABC123!
```